# Opensuse 11.1 KDE4 Dropbox autostart issue

Tags: dropbox, opensuse, kde-4

I am using KDE4 with the lastest version of opensuse, and I want to autostart everytime I turn on my computer.

I followed this website:
http://antrix.net/journal/techtalk/dropbox_kde.html

I got dropbox to work and everything is fine. I created a symlink to the dropboxd file to my ~/.kde4/AUtostart, but does not work.

The command line I used to create the symlink is:
ln -s ~/.dropbox-dist/dropdoxd ~/.kde4/Autostart/

I've check the symlink itself to see where it "pointed to" in it's properties, and it was the right file. The drobox-dist folder is in my /home/"username", and the dropboxd does work. I've tried using "sudo ln -s ~/.dropbox-dist/dropdoxd ~/.kde4/Autostart/" but no symlink was created.

I've checked other blogs and they all say the same things to make dropbox to autostart up, yet it is not working.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Are you already connected to the internet by the time KDE starts up, or are you, e.g., using a wireless modem that only connects later?

Answer (score 1):

Remove/unlink the system link to dropboxd and create a script: start-dropbox.sh which consists of the following command:

~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd >/dev/null 2>&1 &

and place that file in ~/.kde/Autostart then don't forget to chmod +x the script. As I understand it, the 2 arrow brackets > shove stdout and stderr down a black hole and the final & tells the program to execute as a daemon. There's also a native KDE project to do this: http://kdropbox.deuteros.es/

Answer (score 0):

Which version of KDE 4 are you using? OpenSUSE 11.1 uses KDE4.1, and if you've been upgrading then you will be having KDE 4.2 installed, which means the symlink you did won't be invoked. Open Dolphin & browse to

```
~/.kde4
```

And list all the directories under it.I think for KDE 4.x, there will be a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the preferences app and go to advanced and them autostart, add dropbox to it (Sorry if i got some of them names of the menus wrong, i don't have my suse box on me now and i run 11.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat .config/autostart/dropbox.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=nice -n 19 ionice -c3 dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

I added the nice and ionice myself, but the dropbox.desktop file comes from Dropbox itself, or, at least, the nautilus-dropbox package.